# How to call an application shortcut in PowerShell and pass arguments

Tags: powershell, administrator, elevated-privileges, shortcut-file

I need to call MSTEST.exe passing arguments as "elevated/admin" from an account which is not an admin, and cannot be. I have created a short cut for MSTest.exe called "MSTest_Elevated.lnk". I can call this and pass parameters via command line and everything works fine, see below:

```
REM Set up test executable variables
REM SET MSTEST_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe"
SET MSTEST_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\MSTest_Elevated.lnk"
SET NUNIT_EXECUTABLE="C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.4\bin\nunit-console.exe"

CD %WORKSPACE%

SET WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS=%WORKSPACE%\TestResults_Integration

REM Create test result folder
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS%\" ECHO "Creating %WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS%"
IF EXIST "%WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS%\" ECHO "%WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS% EXISTS"
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS%\" md "%WORKSPACE_TEST_RESULTS%"

REM Run the tests
%MSTEST_EXECUTABLE% /resultsfile:"MyServiceTestsResults.trx" /testcontainer:"MyService\Test\Unit\MyServiceTests\bin\Release\MyServiceTests.dll" /nologo 

REM Clear up test executable variables
SET MSTEST_EXECUTABLE=
SET NUNIT_EXECUTABLE=
```

However my solution cannot use command line and needs to use PowerShell. I can call MSTEST from PowerShell like so, but not as admin. It also fails if I try and call the elevated shortcut.

```
Execute-Command -commandTitle "MSTest" -commandPath "`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\mstest.exe`"" -commandArguments "/xml:`"MyServiceTestsResults.trx`" `"MyService\Test\Unit\MyServiceTests\bin\Release\MyServiceTests.dll`" /nologo ";
```

The shortcut seems to run without failing but MSTEST does not get called. So...

*Is there a way to call **MSTest.exe** via the **elevated shortcut**, with **parameters** in the same way in **PowerShell** as I can from call it from a **BAT** file?*